# Unificando linhas

Tags: r

Possuo um base de dados onde as informações estão em linhas diferentes, e queria unifica-las em uma só e ignorando os NA. As linhas serão agrupadas pela variável ID e tempo. Exemplo da base de dados:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,1,2),
                 tempo = c("T0", "T0", "T1", "T3","T3","T0","T4"),
                 var1 = c(1,NA,2, NA,4,NA,NA),
                 var2 = c(NA,"A","C", "A",NA,NA,NA),
                 var3 = c(NA, NA, "2022-01-01", "2021-01-05",NA,"2022-08-24",NA))
```

A base final ficaria:

```
df2 <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,2,2),
                 tempo = c("T0", "T1", "T3","T4"),
                 var1 = c(1,2,4,NA),
                 var2 = c("A","C", "A",NA),
                 var3 = c("2022-08-24","2022-01-01", "2021-01-05",NA))
```

Tente utilizar o group_by pelas duas variáveis (ID e tempo) e summarise, mas não consegui uma função que pegasse o valor que não fosse NA.
A base original possui aproximadamente 260 colunas (coloquei só as 5 primeiras variáveis no exemplo). E quando no agrupamento a variável não possuir preenchimento deve manter o NA, como exemplo o ID 2 e tempo T4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eis uma solução com `summarise`. Depois de agrupar, remova os `NA` com `na.omit` e fique só com o primeiro valor de cada grupo.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))

df %>%
  group_by(ID, tempo) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ first(na.omit(.))), .groups = "drop")
#  # A tibble: 4 × 5
#       ID tempo  var1 var2  var3      
#    <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <chr> <chr>     
#  1     1 T0        1 A     2022-08-24
#  2     1 T1        2 C     2022-01-01
#  3     2 T3        4 A     2021-01-05
#  4     2 T4       NA <NA>  <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>